# Bind9 DNS flavors

Tags: linux, networking, dns, cache, bind

I'm trying to understand how you would use a "Bind9 DNS linux server" in the real world. I have read that there are different "flavors" of DNS servers; authoritative-only server, caching, and forwarding.
Can someone share with me what a company, say with 250 users, may have as there DNS server setup? Here are 4 servers in my example so you can see what I'm trying to figure out.

1. caching DNS server
2. authoritative-only DNS server (primary)
3. authoritatvie-only DNS server (secondary)
4. what could this typically be?

Where would the "Forwarding DNS server" fit into this example? Or would you combine this with the Caching DNS server?

Is there another type of Bind9 DNS server I haven't listed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS is actually quite a complicated subject. So understand what I say here is very much "broad strokes". To understand the different kinds of DNS service you first have to understand [the anatomy of a DNS query](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-comparison-of-dns-server-types-how-to-choose-the-right-dns-configuration#the-path-of-a-dns-query).

### The gist of DNS.

To summarize (and simplify), a DNS query takes a hostname... say `myserver1.example.com`... and asks the DNS server configured in your system's settings (your "local DNS server") to give it the IP address that matches that hostname. Then things can go one of two ways. If the local DNS server knows the ip address that matches that hostname, it simply replies with the correct answer.

However, if it doesn't know the correct answer, it must ask another DNS server on the internet to give it the answer. To find out which DNS server it should ask (which DNS server is **authoritative** for that hostname) it queries the DNS "Root" servers. These are the authoritative servers for "top level domains" such as `.com`, `.info`, etc. It asks the root servers what the authoritative DNS server is for, in our example case, the domain `example.com`. The root servers send your local DNS server the ip address of all servers that are authoritative for "example.com" and your local DNS server then queries those authoritative servers for the ip address matching `myserver1.example.com`. When it gets a reply it then **forwards** that reply to the original device that made the query.

So an authoritative DNS server is one that has final say on what query matches with which result and a forwarding DNS server is one that forwards querys to authoritative dns servers when it doesnt have the answer it self. So how can a forwarding DNS server have the answer itself? By **caching** past results. In which case the first query will take a long time (in computer time) to get a result but any future queries for the same hostname will get a result very, very quickly. Consider that to load a single web page a browser must often lookup a dozen hostnames... often the same ones it looked up last time it visited that site. Having one or more caching domain servers on premises can make the internet you already have feel much more responsive to users.

So in the above example our forwarding DNS server is also a caching DNS server. These can also be authoritative DNS servers for your company. In which case they would also not need to forward requests for hostnames for which your own DNS servers are authoritative... they can simply reply with the answer.

But! And this is important. You should never ever operate with only one authoritative DNS server. In fact, many registrars will simply refuse to allow it for publicly visible authoritative DNS servers. This isn't because of performance concerns but rather due to a need for redundancy in the DNS infrastructure the internet is so dependent on. A secondary authoritative server is in all ways just like any other DNS server except that it tries to keep records it is authoritative for synchronized with another (primary) authoritative server. This means when you go to update records you would do so on the primary authoritative server and the changes would quickly propagate to any secondary authoritative servers you may have. How quickly depends a great deal on configuration of the DNS servers in question.

### So lets move on to your example.

A single forwarding DNS server is enough to handle the load of 250 users. Having a second forwarding DNS server is a good idea simply in case of failure... so as not to interrupt the work day. It's important that the forwarding servers be configured to only forward queries from your local network. Idealy these servers wouldn't even be reachable from the internet, but there may be cases where that is needed. It's important in such cases to ensure your company's resources are not being consumed by internet freeloaders. You would also, ideally, configure these servers to cache results for a time.

As for authoritative DNS... well... that depends on what you want to accomplish. If you are trying to make it possible for the various machines on your network to find each other by host name instead of IP address then you first need static IP addresses assigned to every device you want to be reachable that way. This will be particularly difficult with portable devices. There are ways to make the records auto update to match IPs assigned by DHCP... but there's a big drop in reliability and associated increase in necessary maintenance. Likely far too much so for 250 users.

You'll then need two authoritative servers... primary and secondary. They can be the same servers as your forwarding/caching servers... but be extra careful to configure the DNS servers not to give authoritative responses to queries originating on the internet. This is not just a matter of conserving resources or even security but also of avoiding polluting the internet's DNS infrastructure with information that is useless outside your local network.

Every device in the network that is going to attempt to lookup the hostnames via either your own authoritative DNS server or forwarding/caching DNS servers will need to have these DNS servers configured as their primary and secondary DNS. In fact, it's ideal for your authoritative DNS servers to also be forwarding servers both to simplify configuration and to ensure there are no pointless queries for internet based hostnames sent to local-only DNS server or vice versa.

You'll also need to develop your own hostname scheme. Word of advice... avoid using `.local` as your TLD. It clashes with decentralized DNS services like mDNS (multicast DNS) common with Apple devices. Best practice is to use your company's domain name and create a subomain (`subdomain.domain.tld`) under which all local hosts are assigned (`myserver1.myoffice1.company.com`, `myworkstation256.myoffice1.company.com`, etc).

Now if you want authoritative DNS servers to publicly host the DNS for your company's domain name (for your website, etc)... then you need to do some soul searching. In almost all cases you are better off paying for managed hosting that includes managed DNS hosting. There are many advantages to this. Everything from improved redundancy (most hosts have 5 or more internet facing dns servers), to better physical placement (hosts can place DNS servers in different datacenters to further improve redundancy and reduce latency for people trying to reach your site), to more advanced configurations (such as using geoip functionality to direct queries to the physically closest dns servers).

Hope that answers your questions.